# How to get Sitecore Official Support help

Tags: support

Sitecore has there own Official Support process where we can create tickets/issues and get help from them.
i.e. http://support.sitecore.net

What is the criteria to be eligible to create tickets/issues to Official Sitecore Support ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to gain access to the Sitecore support site you need to be a Sitecore certified developer. There are both instructor lead classroom and eLearning options available.

You can learn more from [Sitecore Training](http://www.sitecore.net/services-and-support/training) about the available classes and options.

At the end of the training class there will be a certification exam. Once you pass the exam you will have access to the Sitecore support site.

Answer (score 8):

There are a couple of criteria in fact.

1. You need to be a certified Sitecore Developer as mentioned above
2. Your Sitecore account - the one you used to register for the exam - needs to be connected to a Sitecore Partner Account.

Essentially, Sitecore Support runs on a "partner view". This is essentially what you want - it allows people access to all support tickets tied to the partner in question. So you can share and access tickets with your colleagues.

Mostly; your account will get connected to your employer's partner account when you pass certification. If not, your boss needs to ask that it gets connected.

There are edge cases; myself for instance - I'm a certified developer but I work freelance - but the partners I work for, switch all the time. The Sitecore setup really has no easy solutions for this setup.

A few caveats; if you're just starting out.

Use a personal email address for your SDN account. Not a partner one your employer gave you. It makes everything easier in the long run when, a few years from now, you switch employers or whatever it may be.

Comment: Does the partner or business also require minimum of two certified developers? Before access is given? @Mark Cassidy

Comment: I don't actually know. These rules have changed around a bit.

Comment: The rules keep changing. It used to be at least 2 developers who were 6.5+ certified. The version number may be higher now. *But* the organisation will not be able to get partner status _before_ this criteria is met (and therefore access to support)

Comment: I'm the only certified developer in my organization and we are a partner and I had access to the support portal.

Comment: Also - you can be associated with a business (since they can have their own developers), it doesn't have to be a partner.

Answer (score 4):

As well as being a Sitecore certified developer (although this restriction can be lifted in certain circumstances) you also have to either:

- Belong to an organisation that has a valid [Sitecore support contract](http://www.sitecore.net/en-gb/services-and-support/support-programs) in place
- Belong to an organisation that is a [Sitecore Solution Partner](http://www.sitecore.net/en-gb/getting-started/partners)

When you raise a ticket you will need to enter a valid Sitecore license number and the system will check to make sure the client is eligible to receive support.